# Reduce an array of numbers to a smaller array of numbers of a fixed length

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Let's say I have an `Array` who's item length is *too big* for some `maxLength`

```
var maxLength = 3;
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var tooBig = arr.length > maxLength;
```

Is there an optimized algorithm for reducing this array in length by combining item values?

```
if(tooBig){
  var newArr = refactor(arr, maxLength);
  console.log(newArr); //[5,5,5]
}
```

Evenly re-distributing as much as possible is important:

```
//Could be reduced more evenly like above
console.log(newArr); //[1,6,8]
```

Comment: What does "*by combining item values*" actually mean? Where is the invariant?

Comment: I've read this question a few times, and still don't get it. What's the purpose/meaning of these numbers? What properties does this array have; what properties should be preserved when shortening it? What is best `[5,5,5]`, `[1,6,8]`, `[1,1,13]`, and why?

Comment: @Thomas Ori sort of beat me to the explanation with his code - he's redistributing total value of the array while preserving integer type. I admit there's more involved after this bit for my specific use case but I didn't want to complicate the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to get the sum of the current array. Extract the reminder, and get an average without the reminder. Then create a new array, and populate it with the average + 1 as long as the reminder is greater than 0.

```js
function refactor(arr, maxLength) {
  var sum = arr.reduce(function(s, n) {
    return s + n;
  });
  
  var remainder = sum % maxLength;
  
  var average = (sum - remainder) / maxLength;
  
  var arr = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    arr.push(average + (i < remainder));
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var maxLength = 3;
var arr = [1,2,3,4,6];
var tooBig = arr.length > maxLength;

if(tooBig){
  var newArr = refactor(arr, maxLength);
  console.log(newArr); //[6,5,5]
}
```

If you don't need the array items to be integers, you can get the average directly, and set it as the value of each array item:

```js
function refactor(arr, maxLength) {
  var average = arr.reduce(function(s, n) {
    return s + n;
  }) / maxLength;
  
  var arr = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    arr.push(average);
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var maxLength = 3;
var arr = [1.7,2.4,3,4,6.934];
var tooBig = arr.length > maxLength;

if(tooBig){
  var newArr = refactor(arr, maxLength);
  console.log(newArr);
}
```

Comment: Oh that is so *clever* I didn't even think of that! I was thinking I'd have to sort on multiple passes but man this greatly simplifies the whole thing.

Comment: you could use the result of the check directly by using it as number: `arr.push(average + (remainder-- > 0))`

Comment: @NinaScholz - good idea. I went with `arr.push(average + (i < remainder))`.

Comment: If you don't care about integers, the solution is even simpler. Just get an average, and fill the array slots with it. See 2nd example.